# How can Angular know what class to Inject if typescript's types is not interpreted at run time?

Tags: angular, typescript, types, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

When we inject a dependency in a component, like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
}

...................

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class MyService {
  constructor() {}
}
```

If, in typescript, types don't exist at runtime, how can angular knows that the parameter my Service needs to receive an instance of `MyService` ???

## Edit:

giving a more concrete problem to solve:

```
class Dependency {}

class Foo {
  constructor(dependency: Dependency) {}
}

type Prototype<T> = new (...args: unknown[]) => T;

function InversionOfControl<T>(Class: Prototype<T>): T {
  /// injects all dependencies of Class and returns a instance of it
}

const foo = InversionOfControl(Foo);
```

How can I, with only typescript and regular javascript, at run time, create this `InversionOfControl` function.

Answer (score 1):

Types don't exist at runtime, but a class is an actual object at runtime. Note that an interface is not a runtime object, and therefore cannot be used as an injection token.

Comment: But when we write `constructor(private myService: MyService) {}` we are typing myService as an instance of MyService, therefore isn't this a type that doesn't exists at runtime ??? How can Angular get the class of a constructor parameter at runtime?

Comment: Dependency injection only works because the class is decorated, the decorator function checks the types and injects the proper object. (needs verification)